# I was trying bubble sort program in scala as I encountered a with Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8

Tags: scala

I know why that error is occuring here. Can anyone help me resolve this error? Also, i dont want to use the two for loops here.

Here is my code:

```
object BubbleSort {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val arr = Array(5, 3, 2, 5, 6, 77, 99, 88)

    var temp = 0
    var n = arr.length
    var fixed = false

    while (fixed == false) {
      fixed == true
      for (i <- 0 to n - 1) {
        if (arr(i) > arr(i + 1)) {

          temp = arr(i + 1)
          arr(i + 1) = arr(i)          
          arr(i) = temp
        
          fixed = false
        }
      }
    }

    for (i <- 0 to n) {
      println("sorted numbers are:" + arr)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `until` instead of `to` because `to` is inclusive in the end whereas `until` is exclusive. - BTW, what do you mean with you do not want to use both loops? There is no way to write a bubble sort without using two loops.

Comment: @TomerShetah I would be pretty sure that nobody would write a bubble sort for any reason that is not learning _(oh well, maybe JS developers that didn't go to a university and [are surprised that things like `split` exist](https://dev.to/itz_giddy/two-string-methods-every-javascript-developer-should-know-10e3), but always remember those are real developers that didn't lose time learning maths but real software tm)_.

Comment: To be fair, bubble sort is the most efficient sort when the sequence is already nearly sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget this comparison `i + 1 < arr.length`. Here is your code running correctly.

```
object BubbleSort {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val arr = Array(5, 3, 2, 5, 6, 77, 99, 88)
    var temp = 0
    var fixed = false

    while (fixed == false) {
      fixed = true
      for (i <- 0 to arr.length - 1) {
        if (i + 1 < arr.length && arr(i) > arr(i + 1)) {
          temp = arr(i + 1)
          arr(i + 1) = arr(i)
          arr(i) = temp
          fixed = false
        }
      }
    }

    arr.foreach(println)
  }
}
```